# Minio and docker-compose, with fixed console ip

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minio

when I run a MinIO container the console ip is picked randomly, here are my configs :

docker-compose

```
services:
  minio:
    container_name: my-minio
    image: bitnami/minio:latest
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: a-good-username
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: a-good-password
      MINIO_DEFAULT_BUCKETS: my-bucket
```

```
$ docker logs my-minio --follow
[...]
minio 08:39:51.67 INFO  ==> ** Starting MinIO **
API: http://localhost:9000 
Finished loading IAM sub-system (took 0.0s of 0.0s to load data).

Console: http://172.18.0.10:9001 http://127.0.0.1:9001
```

I can access it with rclone :

```
[minio-local]
type = s3
provider = Minio
access_key_id = a-good-username
secret_access_key = a-good-password
endpoint = http://172.18.0.10:9000
```

I'd like to have the ip address `http://172.18.0.10` configurable and fixed, is this possible? I've seen similar topics for example with the `MINIO_SERVER_URL: 127.0.0.1` env var, but no success on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore that IP address entirely.  It's an internal address that's randomly chosen by Docker.  You must be on a native-Linux host, and not working remotely from it; on any other setup that IP address would be unreachable.

Instead, add the console port 9001 to your Compose `ports:` block:

```yaml
ports:
  - '9000:9000' # API
  - '9001:9001' # console
```

(You can change the *first* number of either or both lines if they conflict with other host ports, but the *second* number must match the 9000 and 9001 the container process is using itself.)

With these `ports:`, you can access the console on `http://localhost:9001` from the same system (and this also works on non-Linux hosts using Docker Desktop), or remotely using your host's DNS name or IP address and port 9001.